# REGEX - find a string that has the same match?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a string "menu-item" but has a digit after it.

```
<li id="menu-item-578" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-578">
```

i can use this regex

```
menu-item-[0-9]*
```

however it matches all the menu-item string, i want to only match the `"menu-item-578"` but not `id="menu-item-578"`[image]

how can i do it?

thank you

Comment: Tag your question with a language.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The marked question is not a duplicate to this, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it works too:

```
(\s)(menu-item-)\d+
```

https://regex101.com/

- `\s` Any whitespace character

Comment: works as well but i have a lot of menu-item with digits not just 578

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: perfect! :D thank you

Comment: What does `\.?` do there?

Comment: it works well with \.? lol

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `menu-item-[0-9]*` not because it matches the same expected substring superfluously but for the reason that it goes beyond that too like matching `menu-item-` in `menu-item-one`.

Besides replacing quantifier with `+`, you have to look if preceding character is not a non-whitespace character:

```
(?<!\S)menu-item-[0-9]+(?=["' ])
```

or if your regex flavor doesn't support lookarounds you may want to do this which may not be precise either:

```
[ ]menu-item-[0-9]+
```

You may also consider following characters using a more strict pattern:

```
[ ]menu-item-[0-9]+["' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a space before, like this:

```
\ menu-item-[0-9]*
```

The first ocurrence has an `"` right before, while the second one has a space.

EDIT: use an online regex editor (like [Regex tester](https://www.google.es/url?q=https://www.regextester.com/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjjjoe4p6raAhWS6aQKHU5UCfYQFggPMAI&usg=AOvVaw2rUkFX3k2mCmjCJFF11fhS) to try this things.

Comment: it highlight all the menu-item aside from the one in id lol can it be more strict to just highlight the one with digit?